# Why Jquery dialogUI allowing to do other work on back end while popup message?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
 $("#window").dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height: 180,
          title: titles,
          width: 500,
          modal: false,
          buttons: {
              "OK": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  if (redirectURL) {
                      window.location = redirectURL;
                  }
              }
          }
      });
```

I can see my dialog box.but I can able to do other work on back side when Dialogu is appears?

is this Jquery dialog doesnot work like alert?

what is the differnce between alert and jquery Dialog Ui?

alert does not allow us to do anything until if you close alert box. is there any way we can do same for jquery dialog?

Thanks

Comment: You need to put an overlay div on top of all the other page elements so that users can't interact with them. There's probably an option to do that with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the following in your declaration:

```
modal : true
```

Modal pop-ups are much like alerts in the fact that you cannot perform any outside options while the pop-up is present.

**For your implementation:**

```
$("#window").dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height: 180,
          title: titles,
          width: 500,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "OK": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  if (redirectURL) {
                      window.location = redirectURL;
                  }
              }
          }
      });
```

If the overlay isn't working - perhaps through some lack of reference for the necessary jQueryUI CSS files, you could add something similar to the following to test it:

**In your CSS** (if you are unable to find this CSS class - it is probably due to a file not being included. If you include it, that should fix your problem)

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

**Then in your dialog declaration**, add the following:

```
open: function(){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
        }
```

I haven't worked with jQueryUI much, but hopefully something like this might help you out.

Comment: Yes I tried using Modal: true. but it still giving me permision to do some work on back end.. I am working in Firefox is that something problem with that?

Comment: That's strange - normally jQueryUI will perform the overlay automatically. I'll add something in that might help you out.

Comment: Awesome its worked for me. thanks Rionmoster.. thanks for your awesome time.. 1000 points for you..:)

Answer (score 0):

try setting modal:true this should work as you want it to.